# styled-components: styled custom component, with some props

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I have a `<Header />` component, which takes a `size` prop. I want to take a Header with a `size` prop, and additionally style it with `styled-components`.

Something like the following, but this obviously doesn't work.

```
const MyHeader = styled(<Header size="huge />)`
  margin-top: 2rem;
`
```

Any ideas how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
const MyHeader = styled(Header)({ ... });
```

For example:

```
const MyHeader = styled(Header)`
  color: red;
`
```

Or if you want:

```
const Temp = () => <Header size="huge" />;
const MyHeader = styled(Header)({ ... });
```

Comment: It doesn't really answer my question. `Header` might come from another lib, `<Header size="huge" />` might change other CSS properties like font-weight. I'd need to dig into `<Header />` itself and copy-paste the initial values, which is not viable

Comment: Not really sure what you mean, you can still pass through props, you don't have to do anything with them.